# Accessing TextArea Inside GridView with JQuery BlockUI

Tags: asp.net

This is driving me nuts!

I am trying to access a TextArea inside the GridView control. The TextArea is popped up when a button on a gridview is clicked. For some reason the textarea.value always contains "    ".

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCategories" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onrowcommand="gvCategories_RowCommand">

    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="button" value="add comment" onclick="showCommentBox()" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
       <div id="commentBox" style="display:none">

     <input type="button" value="move comment input box" onclick="moveComment()" /> 


    <textarea id="txtComment" rows="10" cols="30">
    </textarea>

    </div>   
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>




function moveComment() {

        alert(document.getElementById("txtComment").value);  

    }
```

I have added this code on the server side but the TextBox always returns " "

```
  protected void gvCategories_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            var row = (GridViewRow) (e.CommandSource as LinkButton).NamingContainer;
            var description = (row.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox).Text;
            lblComment.Text = description; 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@Azam -** This is related to your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912804/jquery-blockui-not-unblocking-the-page) which I answered. The gridview is generating the commentBox DIV along with all its child elements multiple times with the same set of IDs.

I ran a test on this and found that each call to `document.getElementById("txtComment")` returns the next matching element in the DOM with that Id until it cycles through the entire collection of matching elements, going back to the first one and then it does it all over again.

This is the reason why you get a blank when trying to access the value of the textarea or textbox for that matter.

You need to modify your call to `showComment()` so that it stores a reference to the element in the given row, then when you call `moveComment()`, it will work on the same element and not just the next element in the DOM with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

try textarea.innerHTML

looking at your code that would be:

```
alert(document.getElementById("txtComment").innerHTML);
```

Comment: Tried it! It returns nothing!

Comment: I think that is because that id is not unique seeing as how there is one per row in your ItemTemplate. You need to add a unique prefix based on row id.

Comment: Thanks! Actually my main purpose if to access the Text of the TextBox on the server side. I have replaced TextArea with TextBox but when the postback happens it return " " in the TextBox.Text property: 

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" />

Comment: Nevermind. I see the code above. I missed that. Do you see the values output on the client. Is this a data issue?